# HP Color LaserJet - bypass out of color toner and print black and white?

Tags: colors, hp-laserjet

I have a HP Color LaserJet CP1215 and it is low on Yellow toner.  The front panel displays error and will not allow any jobs to print.   Is there a way to bypass this and force it to print - even if only black and white?    I tried setting the printer preferences / defaults to black and white 'yes' and that did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the CP1210 Series Toolbox and open **System Settings**, then enable **Cartridge Out Override**, apply.

Answer (score 2):

A HP website article helped me: [HP Color LaserJet 2600n Printer - Cartridge Out Override](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c00314429-3%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01&sp4ts.oid=446153&ac.admitted=1405623295050.876444892.199480143).

The changes are made on the actual printer. Just follow the guide. A summary:

> Cartridge Out Override can only be enabled from the printer's control panel menu.
>
> [...]
>
> The Cartridge Out Override feature allows the printer to continue using a cartridge that has reached the recommended replacement point. The Override feature will allow the printing even if a cartridge runs completely out of toner. Print Quality Issues including but not limited to the following can occur by running a cartridge beyond its useful life.
>
> [...]
>
> 1. From the main menu, press RIGHT ARROW to System setup and press SELECT [image].
> 2. Press RIGHT ARROW to Print quality and press SELECT.
> 3. Press RIGHT ARROW to Replace supplies and press SELECT.
> 4. Press RIGHT ARROW to Override out and press SELECT.
> 5. Press SELECT.
>
> If Stop at out is selected, the printer will stop printing when a cartridge reaches the recommended replacement point. If Override out is selected, the printer will continue printing when a cartridge reaches the recommended replacement point. The factory default setting is Stop at out.

Comment: The other solution is better because it works and is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

linux hplip not have "override" option. Then the solution could be turn off cp1215 printer, press both printer front panel button (page feed and cancel buttons) at same time and without release this buttons turn on printer, wait that leds blinking and release both buttonn, next print your desire.

alternatively will print one test page togheter your print job.

Comment: Thank you for this, just a shame its manual but it did the trick on my cp1217 with low yellow.

Comment: This worked for me and I did not have to spend hours finding the software for the other solution.

Answer (score -1):

With the printer turned off, and USB unplugged from your computer, press print on your computer.  Plug in USB, then turn on printer.  It will try to print while making print noises, then it will stop and go silent for about 5 seconds.  Then it will try again, and this time it will print.  This works EVERY time for me.